# Chemical Potential with Pressure at Constant Temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

[image: Gibbs free energy of a solid, liquid and gas vary with pressure]

The above picture shows how the Gibbs free energy of a solid, liquid and gas vary with pressure.

I have found no similar graphs on the internet that match the above. Instead I often find these graphs :

[image: Chemical Potential Variation with Pressure]

My questions are :

1.) How can both the two graphs correct ? Since their gradients are different.

2.) In the first picture; why is the gas curve a curve in the first place ? Why isn't it a straight line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, I've figured it out.

$(\partial G/\partial p)_T = V$

Substituting V for $nRT/P$ and integrating gives us a logarithmic relationship.